# Free library for .NET JPG compression?

Tags: .net, image-processing, jpeg

I am looking for a high-quality free JPG compression library with C# interface, as an alternative to the standard `Image` class of .NET.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Duplicate? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1669850/jpeg-compression-with-high-quality-in-c

Comment: It is pointless to ask for a *better* one when you don't specify what kind of better you need.

Comment: I am looking for a library that yields higher quality JPG compression than the standard JPG codec in .NET can provide. With all quality params maxed out, standard JPG routine lags far behind the quality of compression that we can achieve with e.g. photoshop compression.

Comment: This question fits exactly in the context of: Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it..

Comment: Does this answer your question? [High quality JPEG compression with c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1669850/high-quality-jpeg-compression-with-c-sharp)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One alternative is [FreeImage](http://freeimage.sourceforge.net/sourcecode.html)

Answer (score 1):

You can try [AForge](http://code.google.com/p/aforge/) but note that all JPEG operations not done with GDI+ are much slower...